# C# linq multiple sorts in one clause

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I'm trying to sort some data using Linq using two sorting methods but it doesn't work.

So I have a list that contains an Id and a Result.

I would like to sort in the following order:

1. Sort the list by the lowest ID wherever the Result = 0
2. Then sort the list by ascending Result
3. But the list can only include Results that are not null

I tried the code below but it appears I can't put a `.Where` in between the `.OrderBy` and the `.ThenBy`.

```
var selectedResults = Results
  .OrderBy(s => s.id)
  .Where(s => s.result == 0)
  .ThenBy(s => s.result)
  .Where(s => s.result != null)                                                    
  .ToList();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: just do the OrderBy and Then clauses last

Comment: I suspect will get more quality responses if you edit your question to include a [mcve] **including sample data** and the expected results for those sample data.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to filter by `s.result == 0` but just by `s.result == null`.

```
var selectedResults = Results
    .Where(s => s.result != null)
    .OrderBy(s => s.result == 0 ? s.id : s.result);
```

If you want to force that the `result==0` items come first add this conditional order:

```
var selectedResults = Results
    .Where(s => s.result != null)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.result == 0) // forces 0 results first even if there are negative
    .ThenBy(s => s.result == 0 ? s.id : s.result);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that fail if the sequence contains an element having `Result < 0 && id > 0` and another element having `result = id = 0`? This will force the nevative result first and then the one having `result = 0`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, but he did not rule it out. _It's not clear that the 0 results should come before the negative results_ sure? I read _1. ... 2. **then**..._. Looks to me like sorting all `Result = 0` first and then all the other values independently whether they are negative or not. But that's only my interpretation.

Comment: For clarity, there will be no negative results. 0 is the lowest result possible. Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score 3):

Put `ThenBy` after `OrderBy` because it only works with `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, when you call `Where` it changes the return type back to `IQueryable<T>` so the `ThenBy` no longer be called. And as the comment points out, it is cheaper to filter the result set before ordering.

```
var selectedResults = Results
                      .Where(s => s.result == 0 && s.result != null)
                      .OrderBy(s => s.id)
                      .ThenBy(s => s.result)                                                 
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: (It'll probably be slightly cheaper to combine the `Where`'s, and put them before the `OrderBy`)

Comment: I guess everyone misunderstood OP. He doesnt want to filter by `s.result == 0`. Also, this doesn't compile: `&& s =>`

Answer (score 2):

If I understands you right,

```
var selectedResults = Results
  .OrderBy(item => item.Result != 0) // items with Result == 0 first
  .ThenBy(item => item.Result == 0   // if items.Result == 0 then by Id
     ? item.id
     : int.MaxValue)                 // I've assumed id is int
  .ThenBy(item => item.Result);      // finally by Result
```

So we'll have something like this

```
   Result | Id
   -----------     
        0 |  1 <- Result == 0 on the top; tie breaks by Id (1, 2, 4)
        0 |  2
        0 |  4
       -1 |  0 <- Result != 0 on the bottom, tie breaks by Result (-1, 7, 8, 9) 
        7 | 15 
        8 |  3
        9 | 98
```

Comment: Your examples are poorly chosen. You'll get the same result using `Results.OrderBy(item => item.Result).ThenBy(item => item.Id)`. Swap id 3 and 4 and your result will show the effect of you code in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You always want to sort on the smallest dataset you can, so I would put the `Where` clauses at the beginning like so:

```cs
var selectedResults = Results
                      .Where(s => s.result == 0 && s.result != null)
                      .OrderBy(s => s.id)
                      .ThenBy(s => s.result)                                                  
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Your `Where` forces `s.Result == 0`. The constraint to `s.Result != null` will be fullfilled by `s.Result == 0` and can be removed and `.ThenBy` won't have any effect if all values are `0`.